# How to test swipe gesture with robolectric?

Tags: android, android-espresso, robolectric

I need to verify that after swipe the needed fragment have been shows. Is there a way to do that with robolectric or espresso?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use something like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.viewId)).perform(swipeRight()); //or swipeLeft()
```

and then

```
onView(withId(R.id.secondViewId)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```